# How to cause Install-Module to also install any required modules?

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-module

I am working on a PS module, which depends on SqlServer.

Here is the module manifest file:

```
@{
    ModuleVersion = "1.0.19103.11"
    GUID = "59bc8fa6-b480-4226-9bcc-ec243102f3cc"
    Author = "..."
    CompanyName = "..."
    Copyright = "..."
    Description = "..."
    RequiredModules = ""
    ScriptsToProcess = "vsts\config.ps1"
    NestedModules = @( ... )
    PrivateData = @{
        PSData = @{
            ExternalModuleDependencies = @(
                "SqlServer"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the commands I use to publish the module:

```
if (Get-PSRepository $PSRepositoryName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Unregister-PSRepository $PSRepositoryName
}
Register-PSRepository $PSRepositoryName `
    -SourceLocation $NuGetRepoUrl `
    -PublishLocation $NuGetRepoUrl `
    -InstallationPolicy Trusted `
    -PackageManagementProvider nuget

Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
```

The problem is that when I install this module I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: The externally managed, dependent module 'SqlServer' is not installed on this computer. To use the current module 'xyz.PS.Core', ensure that its dependent
module 'SqlServer' is installed.
```

How can I cause the SqlServer to be installed automatically when this package is installed without any warning.

I tried setting the `RequiredModules` property, but this fails to publish the module in the first place, if the build machine does not have the module SqlServer installed. I can install it there, but is there a better way without forcing us to install packages on the build agents?

**EDIT 1**

So, I installed the SqlServer module on the build agent and added the `RequiredModules` property. The same warning is displayed. But now I cannot even import the module:

```
Import-Module : The required module 'SqlServer' is not loaded. Load the module or remove the module from 'RequiredModules' in the file
```

**EDIT 2**

I am still unable to make it work. Let me show all the combinations. In all the cases, the test machine does **not** have the SqlServer module installed on it.

**Attempt 1**

```
RequiredModules = @(
    @{
        ModuleName = "SqlServer"
        ModuleVersion = "21.1.18068"
    }
)
PrivateData = @{
    PSData = @{
        ExternalModuleDependencies = "SqlServer"
    }
}
```

Yields

```
C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
PowerShellGet cannot resolve the module dependency 'SqlServer' of the module 'xyz.PS.Core' on the repository 'xyz-QA'. Verify that the dependent module 'SqlServer' is available in the repository 'xyz-QA'. If this dependent module 'SqlServer' is managed externally, add it to the ExternalModuleDependencies entry in the PSData section of the module manifest.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 char:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-PSArtifactUtility], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolveModuleDependency,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
C:\>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
RequiredModules = @("SqlServer")
PrivateData = @{
    PSData = @{
        ExternalModuleDependencies = "SqlServer"
    }
}
```

Yields

```
C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
PowerShellGet cannot resolve the module dependency 'SqlServer' of the module 'xyz.PS.Core' on the repository 'xyz-QA'. Verify that the dependent module 'SqlServer' is available in the repository 'xyz-QA'. If this dependent module 'SqlServer' is managed externally, add it to the ExternalModuleDependencies entry in the PSData section of the module manifest.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 char:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-PSArtifactUtility], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolveModuleDependency,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
C:\>
```

**Attempt 3**

```
PrivateData = @{
    PSData = @{
        ExternalModuleDependencies = "SqlServer"
    }
}
```

(no `RequiredModules`) Yields:

```
C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
C:\> Get-Module SqlServer -ListAvailable
C:\> Install-Module xyz.PS.Core -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
WARNING: The externally managed, dependent module 'SqlServer' is not installed on this computer. To use the current module 'xyz.PS.Core', ensure that its dependent module 'SqlServer' is installed.
C:\> Get-Module SqlServer -ListAvailable
C:\>
```

As you can see, publish is successful, but installing the module outputs a warning. And no SqlServer installed.

**Attempt 4**

```
RequiredModules = @(
    @{
        ModuleName = "SqlServer"
        ModuleVersion = "21.1.18068"
    }
)
```

(without the ExternalModuleDependencies) Yields:

```
C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
The specified RequiredModules entry 'SqlServer' in the module manifest 'C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\2144858157\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.psd1' is invalid. Try again after updating this entry with valid values.At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1144 char:27+ ... oduleInfo = Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest -Path $mani ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mkhari...ce.PS.Core.psd1:String) [Test-ModuleManifest], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidRequiredModulesinModuleManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand
C:\>
```

**Attempt 5**

```
RequiredModules = @("SqlServer")
```

(without the ExternalModuleDependencies) Yields:

```
C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
The specified RequiredModules entry 'SqlServer' in the module manifest 'C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\1208648280\xyz.PS.Core\xyz.PS.Core.psd1' is invalid. Try again after updating this entry with valid values.At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1144 char:27+ ... oduleInfo = Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest -Path $mani ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mkhari...ce.PS.Core.psd1:String) [Test-ModuleManifest], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidRequiredModulesinModuleManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand
C:\>
```

So, nothing I do works. So far it seems Powershell cannot install a required module.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 3**

The RequiredModules property does not work even if I install SqlServer on the build machine. Observe:

```
RequiredModules = @(
    "SqlServer"
)
PrivateData = @{
    PSData = @{
        ExternalModuleDependencies = "SqlServer"
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```
C:\> Get-Module SqlServer -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\Users\mkharitonov\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     21.1.18102 SqlServer                           {Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDatabase, Add-SqlAvailabilityGroupListenerStaticIp, Ad...


C:\> Publish-Module -Name $ModuleManifestFile -NuGetApiKey $NuGetApiKey -Repository $PSRepositoryName -Force
PowerShellGet cannot resolve the module dependency 'SqlServer' of the module 'xyz.PS.Core' on the repository 'xyz-QA'. Verify that the dependent module 'SqlServer' is available in the repository 'xyz-QA'. If this dependent module 'SqlServer' is managed externally, add it to the ExternalModuleDependencies entry in the PSData section of the module manifest.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 char:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-PSArtifactUtility], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolveModuleDependency,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
C:\>
```

Powershell seems to look for the SqlServer module in my repository rather than in PSGallery. I do not understand way. Here are the PS repositories registered on the machine:

```
C:\> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Trusted              https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
xyz-QA                    Trusted             http://devstatic.xyz.com/nugetserver/nuget


C:\>
```

So, I truly do not understand what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Your 4th attempt is working as designed. The other attempts either do not use a fully-qualified module name (attempt 2), or do not use an array for external dependencies (attempts 1, 2, and edit 3). As for attempt 4 and 5, the `DirectoryNotFoundException ` indicates a precondition for the manifest is not met: required modules must be installed locally for publish the work.

Comment: The warning in attempt 4 is by design because PowerShellGet does not want to try and solve cross-repository dependencies and any problems that may cause with `Update-Module` later. So the warning says you need to install some dependencies, and if you do, you will have run `Install-Module` for the dependency yourself, so you should know what to expect when running `Update-Module`for that dependency at some point in the future.

Answer (score 10):

*Update*:

- Specifying *just* `RequiredModules` for *intra*-repository dependencies (not *also* `PrivateData.PSData.ExternalModuleDependencies`) may be sufficient as of PackageManagement v1.4.8.1 / PowerShellGet v2.2.5 - see the first comment below.
- A rewritten version of PowerShellGet that no longer depends on the PackageManagement module is forthcoming (as of this writing), named [PSResourceGet](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet).

---

Note: The following was gleaned form [this discussion in the PackageManagement (OneGet) GitHub repo](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/164), notably [this comment](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/164#issuecomment-314508621) from a team member:

> `Install-Module` works for dependences within the same repo.
> For dependency modules are hosted on the repo different from that module to be installed, I recommend you to publish them to your house repo.
> If you do not wish to publish them into your house repo, you may save modules to your common file share, Register-PSRepository -Name local -SourceLocation \server\commonshare, then install these modules from file share first."

As of [PackageManagement module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.3.1) version 1.3, I conclude from your symptoms that the above still applies, even though the comment is from mid 2017 (I couldn't find any official documentation).

**To summarize:**

- Automatic installation of ***cross-repository* dependencies isn't supported**; the **workaround is to publish the external dependencies to your in-house repo as well**.
- On calling **`Publish-Module`**, seemingly, **modules listed in the `RequiredModules` entry *must* be present in the same target repo**.

  - That is, the presence of such modules on your machine alone is *not* enough. (I'm unclear on whether they *also* need to be present - they shouldn't have to be.)
- To support automatic installation of *intra-repository* dependencies, the `PrivateData.PSData.ExternalModuleDependencies` entry must list those dependencies *too - in addition to `RequiredModules`* - *by name only* - see below.

**Specifying *intra-repository* module dependencies (unverified) for automatic dependency installation**:

```
# Specify what other modules this module requires to work, using a FQMN,
# (a Fully Qualified Module Name), via a hashtable.
# The 'ModuleVersion' entry version numbers specifies a *minimum* required version 
# number; 'RequiredVersion' specifies an *exact* version, and  
# 'MaximumVersion' specifies a maximum version.
# IMPORTANT:
#   If you publish a module whose manifest has a 'RequiredModules'
#   entry to a repository with Publish-Module, all referenced modules
#   seemingly *must exist in that repository.*
RequiredModules = @( @{ModuleName = 'SqlServer'; ModuleVersion = '21.1.18068' } )


PrivateData = @{
  PSData = @{

    # ... 

    # !! This field is *ancillary* to the more detailed 'RequiredModules' field and
    # !! must reference the *same modules*, but by *names only*,
    # !! in order to automatically install other modules
    # !! *from the same repository* that this module depends on.
    # !! To be safe, specify even a *single* name as an *array*
    # !! (While this is not a general requirement in manifests, 
    # !!  it may be necessary here due to a bug.)
    ExternalModuleDependencies = @('SqlServer')
}
```

As an aside: A bug in `New-ModuleManifest` currently prevents direct creation of the `PrivateData.PSData.ExternalModuleDependencies` entry:

```
# !! BROKEN as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0;
# The inner hashtable ends up represented as 'System.Collections.Hashtable'
New-ModuleManifest someManifest.psd1 -PrivateData @{ 
  PSData = @{
    ExternalModuleDependencies = @('SqlServer')
  }
}
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5922).

Comment: If by 'intra-repository' dependencies you mean dependencies that reside in the same repository, then from my experiments with Windows PowerShell 5.1. and PowerShellGet 2.2.5 you only need to add the dependencies to `RequiredModules`. They will be added to the NuGet package's `Dependencies` metadata, and thus will be automatically installed. So the `ExternalModuleDependencies` is **not** necessary for this, and in fact achieves the opposite. Modules listed in `ExternalModuleDependencies` will be **excluded** from the NuGet packages `Dependencies` metadata, and thus not installed automatically.

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout, that would certainly be more convenient; I've added a note at the top of the answer that points to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comprehensive answer by @mklement0 there is **a possibility to avoid persistent publishing the external dependencies to your in-house repo**, and so avoid unwanted redundancy and maintenance efforts:

Therefore you can use a [repository manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository#Repository_managers) like Sonatype's Nexus which provides the [repository grouping](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-RepositoryGroup) feature:

> They [repository groups] allow you to combine multiple repositories and other repository groups in a single repository. This in turn means that your users can rely on a single URL for their configuration needs, while the administrators can add more repositories and therefore components to the repository group.

So you have to create a *nuget-group* which combines the nuget formatted repositories (e.g. *nuget-hosted* (your PowerShell modules) and *powershellgallery.com-proxy* (external dependencies)) into a single repository.

With this you need to publish the external dependencies (from powershellgallery.com) to your in-house repo (*nuget-hosted*) for publishing of your developed PowerShell module only (`Publish-Module -Repository nuget-hosted -Name ...`). Afterwards you can remove the external dependency from *nuget-hosted*.

For `Install-Module` of the developed module together with the dependencies on an arbitrary PowerShell machine you have to register and use the *nuget-group* repository only.