# How can I ensure that a 3rd party module is loaded in my custom script module?

Tags: powershell

I have a custom script module and one of the functions depends on the AWSPowerShell module. I attempted to put `Import-Module AWSPowerShell` inside that function, but when this runs on the server it fails and says no valid module is found. If I try `Import-Module AWSPowerShell` from the command line on the same server running as the same user it works fine. There seems to be something wrong with calling `Import-Module` from inside another module.

I saw that NestedModules can be used to specify dependencies so I added `NestedModules @('AWSPowerShell')` to the module manifest and removed the `Import-Module AWSPowerShell` from the function that needs it.

Now the error about AWSPowerShell happens at the point where I import my own custom module from the calling script.

The exact error is: `Import-Module : The module to process 'AWSPowerShell', listed in field 'NestedModules' of module manifest 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\...MyModule.psd1' was not processed because no valid module was found in any module directory.`

I did notice that the AWSPowerShell module is installed in a different folder path than my custom module. My module is in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and AWSPowerShell is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell`.

How can I set this up so that AWSPowerShell can be loaded for use inside my module?

**Update**
I made a copy of the AWSPowerShell module folder under `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` and now the module imports successfully using the NestedModules method. Everything I saw about NestedModules appeared to be for combining modules that were being developed for a bigger solution. I'm not sure about using this technique for importing a 3rd party module like this. I may be misusing this feature.

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell` suggests that the module was installed from the _32-bit_ version of Windows PowerShell. Installing it from the 64-bit version should make it available to your module (assuming it is run from the 64-bit version) too; apart from that, the `RequiredModules` module-manifest entry is for referencing independently installed modules; please see my answer.

Comment: P.S.: The list of directories for PowerShell's [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading), i.e. those directories in which `Import-Module` can discover modules by their name alone, is stored in `$env:PSModulePath`.

Answer (score 5):

- The `NestedModule` module-manifest (`.psd1`) entry  is for modules that are *bundled with your module* and available in your module's code only.
- `RequiredModules` is for importing *independently pre-installed modules*, which are imported into the *global* scope when your module is imported, which means that their commands are also available to the caller.

Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670447/45375) shows how to specify `RequiredModules` modules to be *installed on demand* by declaring them as *external dependencies*, but the limitation appears to be that both the module and its dependency must come from the *same repository* and must be installed with [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module).

Comment: This answer clears up many doubts. The 32/64 conflict is also a great lead on this problem. With this information I'm sure I can get this sorted out.